# When should we specify a Key parameter in Flutter widget constructors?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters

I am very new to Flutter & Dart. After reading some codes from several sources, I am wondering whether or not I should specify `Key key` parameter whenever I implement Flutter widget constructors. Some code I found do not use `Key key` parameter and other code extensively use it.

The following snippet is copied from [StatelessWidget class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) section. It uses `Key key` parameter.

```
class Frog extends StatelessWidget {
  const Frog({
    Key key,
    this.color = const Color(0xFF2DBD3A),
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: color, child: child);
  }
}
```

## Question

When should we specify a `Key` parameter in Flutter widget constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the framework matches widgets in the current and previous build according to their runtimeType and the order in which they appear. With keys, the framework requires that the two widgets have the same key as well as the same runtimeType.

Keys are most useful in widgets that build many instances of the same type of widget. For example, the ShoppingList widget, which builds just enough ShoppingListItem instances to fill its visible region:

> Without keys, the first entry in the current build would always sync with the first entry in the previous build, even if, semantically, the first entry in the list just scrolled off screen and is no longer visible in the viewport.

> By assigning each entry in the list a “semantic” key, the infinite list can be more efficient because the framework syncs entries with matching semantic keys and therefore similar (or identical) visual appearances. Moreover, syncing the entries semantically means that state retained in stateful child widgets remains attached to the same semantic entry rather than the entry in the same numerical position in the viewport.

Take a look at this video, it's from the flutter team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it means that always specifying the keys is a good practice?

Comment: @NotAZoomedImage Only if you find yourself adding, removing, or reordering a collection of widgets of the same type that hold some state. Most of the time you don’t need keys.